# Microsoft Word drop down box for row in table entry

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

Good afternoon
I am wondering if it is possible in Microsoft word to implement a drop down box where selecting an entry will fill data across a row in a table, example of table as below. id like selecting someone's name to auto populate the mobile phone entry of the table as well.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ppH.png

any assistance would be appreciated,

thanks for you time

Comment: Sure. One option is to use macros,  it's more complicated,  but looks more "Word". Other - easier - option is to embed an Excel sheet.

Comment: Thanks I Knew Macros where an option but they seemed out of my capability, Will investigate embedding an excel sheet as aesthetics is not an issue

Answer (score 1):

Sure. One option is to use macros, it's more complicated, but looks more "Word". Other - easier - option is to embed an Excel sheet. – Máté Juhász 18 hours ago